# Can't get file name? Always null

Tags: java, html

HTML

```
                        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="addCompany">
                            <fieldset>
                                <legend>Add Company</legend>
                                <br/>
                                <label>Company Name:</label>
                                <input name="name" size="30" type="text"/>
                                <br/>
                                <label>Company Logo:</label>
                                <input name="file" size="30" type="file"/>
                                <br/>
                                <span id="updateError" class="errorMessage"></span>
                                <button type="submit" class="jUiButton">Submit</button>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>     
                        <script>$(".jUiButton").button()</script>
```

Java Servlet

```
// Check that we have a file upload request
        boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
        if(isMultipart && request.getContentType() != null)
        {
            // Create a factory for disk-based file items
            FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

            // Create a new file upload handler
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

            // Parse the request
            List /* FileItem */ items = null;
            try
            {
                items = upload.parseRequest(request);
            }
            catch(FileUploadException e) {}

            // Process the uploaded items
            Iterator iter = items.iterator();

            FileItem cvFile = null;
            while(iter.hasNext())
            {
                FileItem item = (FileItem)iter.next();

                if(item.isFormField())
                {
                    if(item.getFieldName().equals("name"))
                        name = item.getString();
                }
                else
                {
                    cvFile = item;
                }

                if(name != null && cvFile != null)
                {
                    directoryName = request.getRealPath("/") + "/Uploads/Companies/" + name + "/";
                    File theDir = new File(directoryName);
                    if (!theDir.exists())
                        theDir.mkdir();

                    File uploadedFile = new File(directoryName + cvFile.getName());
                    try
                    {
                        cvFile.write(uploadedFile);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {}
                }
            }
```

I get a null exception here (in the last if statement):

```
File uploadedFile = new File(directoryName + cvFile.getName());
```

Comment: For what it's worth, don't eat those `Exception`s. At least write the stack trace to a log or stdout.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with your code (and I'm not even a Java guy).

```
FileItem cvFile = null;
```

You set cvFile to null here.

```
while(iter.hasNext())
{
   FileItem item = (FileItem)iter.next();

   if(item.isFormField())
   {
     if(item.getFieldName().equals("name"))
        name = item.getString();
   }
   else
   {
      cvFile = item;
   }
```

If the first branch of the if is take (`item.isFormField()`), `cvFile` remains null (its value never changes from where it was initialized).

```
File uploadedFile = new File(directoryName + cvFile.getName());
```

You use `cvFile.getName()` here, but `cvFile` may still be null.

Comment: I thought that's what it was initially, too. But around the suspected NPE line, he has a `if(name != null && cvFile != null)`, which would make `cvFile` apparently not the null object in that statement. However, I really don't see what else in that statement would be null. I wonder if the code is really the exact code that was executed when the NPE occurred.

Comment: makes no difference. I put FileItem before the boolean, same result.

Comment: @Rob Huska, you're right. I missed the test for null further down. But I don't see anywhere else it could be, and the line in question accesses `directoryname` and `cvFile.getName()`; at that point, AFAICS, `cvFile` is the only thing that could be null and cause the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you set cvFile.name to something, either via setName or otherwise? I think your name is null. I don't see it set on item. I think see cvFile is assigned to an object, but the name object you try access via getName is null.

Comment: It's also worth noting that new File(path), throws a NullPointerException in the case where the path is null.